# Search XML content in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file:

With [some help of StackOverflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851971/parse-updateinfo-xml) I managed to achieve some of what I planned to do. Now, I want to add a search function to my script and singularly work on that sub-tree. For example, I ask the user - what ID? He enters `AL2012-2015-088`. Recursively searching for this ID in a huge XML file, the script should find this ID and print the elements it has.

I used `content.find("AL2012-2015-088")`, but it won't work!

Comment: What do you mean you used `content.find()`? What library are you using and where is your python code?

Comment: The answer to *hir* last question pointed at the `xml.etree` module.

Comment: Hi! I am using ElementTree. I use it like this - 
ids = content.find("id")

Answer (score 2):

If you would switch to [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), you would be able to use the full power of XPath expressions (you would also speed things up dramatically).

Here is an example - locating the `update` element with a desired `id` and printing out the `title`:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

id_that_user_enters = "AL2012-2015-088"
tree = ET.parse("example.xml")

update = tree.xpath("//update[id = '%s']" % id_that_user_enters)[0]
print(update.findtext("title"))
```

Prints:

```
Amazon Linux 2012.03 - AL2012-2015-088: medium priority package update for gnutls
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the find command is designed to find tags as opposed to the text within the tags so you should do find on `id`. I'm not sure which info you need from the XML, but here is an example that gets the title.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as elt
content = elt.parse('example.xml').getroot()

def get_id_info(inputID):
    for child in content:
        if child.find('id').text == inputID:
            print child.find('title').text

get_id_info('AL2012-2014-001')
```

gives `Amazon Linux 2012.03 - AL2012-2014-001...`

Comment: This seems to be partially working for me.

I have -   for child in tree:
   if child.find('id').text == amazon_id:
    print "[+] %r found in %r!" %(amazon_id, xmlfile)
  else:
   print "[!] %r not found in %r!" %(amazon_id, xmlfile)

amazon_id, xmlfile are taken from sys.argv. This returns -
'AL2012-2014-001' found in 'xml.xml'!
'AL2012-2014-001' found in 'xml.xml'!
'AL2012-2014-001' not found in 'xml.xml'!

How can I correct this?

Comment: I think I know what is happening. The XML file I have has 100 trees and hence this is running 100 times! How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems more like a question about your data than the programming. Looks like `"AL2012-2014-001"` shows up multiple times in your XML file, so you need to decide what to do with that information like count the number of occurrences, such as `counter = 0` and `if child.find('id').text == amazon_id: counter = counter  + 1`

Comment: I have just one unique entry and the XML is well formed.