# Element Tree - Seaching for specific element value without looping

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file which a bunch of repeating blocks of xml .  I want to extract the Listing Price only if the offer has a specific `SellerId` and my item has `SubCondtion='New'`. I can do it now by looping over the offers and checking the `OfferSellerId` in the xml block against my seller id and making sure the `Subcondition = 'New'` but I am wondering if there is a way to grab the `ListingPrice` usng `find` or `findall` checking if the `SellerId` and `SubCondition` in the same `<Offer>` block has these specific value using only element tree logic rather then having a loop over each offer.

Current Code

```
for offer in root.findall('./NotificationPayload/AnyOfferChangedNotification/Offers/'):
        OfferSellerId = offer.find('SellerId').text
        SubCondition = offer.find('SubCondition').text

        if (SellerId == OfferSellerId && SubCondition == 'New'):
          ListingPrice  = offer.find('ListingPrice/Amount').text
```

xml

```
  .......
  <Offers>
        <Offer>
            <SellerId>A2LZYV</SellerId>
            <SubCondition>new</SubCondition>
            <SellerFeedbackRating>
                <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>100</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                <FeedbackCount>929</FeedbackCount>
            </SellerFeedbackRating>
            <ShippingTime minimumHours="24" maximumHours="48" availabilityType="NOW"/>
            <ListingPrice>
                <Amount>16.69</Amount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
                <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </Shipping>
            <ShipsFrom>
                <Country>US</Country>
                <State>FL</State>
            </ShipsFrom>
            <IsFulfilledByAmazon>false</IsFulfilledByAmazon>
            <IsBuyBoxWinner>false</IsBuyBoxWinner>
            <PrimeInformation>
                <IsPrime>false</IsPrime>
                <IsNationalPrime>false</IsNationalPrime>
            </PrimeInformation>
            <IsFeaturedMerchant>true</IsFeaturedMerchant>
            <ShipsDomestically>true</ShipsDomestically>
        </Offer>
        ......
```

Comment: `If you would switch to lxml.etree, you would be able to use the full power of XPath expressions (you would also speed things up dramatically).` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901802#36903566

Comment: @ChrisHappy - ElementTree's limited xpath support should be enough in this case. (See my answer for an example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though [ElementTree has limited XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), it should be sufficient enough to do what you want...

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```xml
<doc>
    <NotificationPayload>
        <AnyOfferChangedNotification>
            <Offers>
                <Offer>
                    <SellerId>A2LZYV</SellerId>
                    <SubCondition>new</SubCondition>
                    <SellerFeedbackRating>
                        <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>100</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                        <FeedbackCount>929</FeedbackCount>
                    </SellerFeedbackRating>
                    <ShippingTime minimumHours="24" maximumHours="48" availabilityType="NOW"/>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <Amount>16.69</Amount>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    </Shipping>
                    <ShipsFrom>
                        <Country>US</Country>
                        <State>FL</State>
                    </ShipsFrom>
                    <IsFulfilledByAmazon>false</IsFulfilledByAmazon>
                    <IsBuyBoxWinner>false</IsBuyBoxWinner>
                    <PrimeInformation>
                        <IsPrime>false</IsPrime>
                        <IsNationalPrime>false</IsNationalPrime>
                    </PrimeInformation>
                    <IsFeaturedMerchant>true</IsFeaturedMerchant>
                    <ShipsDomestically>true</ShipsDomestically>
                </Offer>
            </Offers>            
        </AnyOfferChangedNotification>
    </NotificationPayload>
</doc>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("test.xml")

SellerId = "A2LZYV"

for price in root.findall(f".//Offer[SellerId='{SellerId}'][SubCondition='new']/ListingPrice/Amount"):
    print(price.text)
```

**Printed Output**

```
16.69
```