# How do I search a word in an XML file in python?

Tags: python, xml

Yes I know I can use find(), findall() using these a problem occurs.
The problem is, suppose you want to find the word "the". If theres a text like father in the xml file, the find function will return true because father has "the" in it. How can I fix this?

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901802/search-xml-content-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific example, but I would recommend checking out [regex in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

For the case mentioned, you'd probably want to do the following:

```
import re
//load the XML file
print(re.search("the",file1))
```

but even then, I'd imagine there are edge cases that don't cover what you really mean by finding the word "the", such as using capitalization with the word.